# Point subdomain to local ip address with a free DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, ip, local, cloudflare

I have two servers with different local IP addresses, and a single domain and dynamic IP.
I would like to know if it's possible to point each subdomain to a specific hostname in my network so they can be accessed globally.

At some point, I used to do this with port forwarding. I had an account in afraid.org, and I simply redirected the subdomain sub.example.com to example.com:3000, it worked fine but it wasn't a pretty solution.

Just recently I moved to cloudflare, and it doesn't seem to be possible to redirect the subdomain to that port anymore, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "local IP addresses"? IP addresses in the [private IPv4 address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)?

Comment: Consider asking it on http://serverfault.com instead... Not necessary on-topic here.

Comment: Yes Bruno, more specifically, one server IP is 192.168.1.200 while the other is 192.168.1.201, I'm not sure if it's possible to have a the subdomain point to one when they are both using the port 80.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare can't proxy port 3000 ([Ports CloudFlare can proxy](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-))